# Microsoft OPEN XML sdk 2.5 on NUGET

Tags: nuget, openxml, openxml-sdk

When Installing the documentFormat.OpenXML from nuget, why does it say **UNOFFICIAL** packaging of Microsoft's OpenXML sdk 2.5 even though its created by Microsoft? if its Unofficial, is there an Official version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unofficial because the DocumentFormat.OpenXml NuGet package was not created by Microsoft.

Whilst the Authors says Microsoft, that is just a text field that can contain anything. The owner is the more important piece of information and that is not Microsoft. NuGet packages created and owned by Microsoft typically have Microsoft as the owner:

https://www.nuget.org/profiles/microsoft

There is also a curated NuGet package feed of Microsoft NuGet packages and those that Microsoft officially support:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/

There is no official Microsoft NuGet package for OpenXml currently.

Comment: I think this is the official nuget package from MS for OpenXml ... https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml